# sapphire 5770 never idles

Tags: overheating

built a new computer with my old graphics card (on older computer it worked just fine, idling at 157/300 core/memory) while on the new pc, it's always on 850/1200 (those freqs are the full load) also catalyst control center shows 99% load all the time. this ends up overheating my whole system after some time and a blue screen appears.
the drivers I used are the last ones (12.10). also tried older ones (12.8, 12.3, 11.10 i think) with no success
any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mining virus, I know exactly how it got there. Was trying to make a game work and I was desperate to see the new rig running so I downloaded a .dll file (bad call). Eliminating the process rundll.exe (or smth like that) made the vga work normally, then with AVG made sure the virus was gone for good.